# Looking for a long webcomic strip, does anyone know what site it belongs to?

Tags: story-identification

This comic strip is about a man, dressed in a cowboy suit who goes into a brothel, a woman who offers her services, can't remember the woman well but I think she was blonde or redhead, talks to him and he starts telling her a story about his unforgettable and terrifying trip to a planet, a space colony that landed on said planet and started hearing this "noise" that drove them insane and made them suicide or something similar. and at the end she's very understanding on his sadness, I've been trying to find this strip since the last time I read it but I don't know the author.

Approx year is 2012-13, it's a long webcomic, just one image, nothing else that I know of, except he escaped the planet when his captain made a sacrifice, that's as far as I can remember.

Comment: Actual comic book(s)? Known publisher? Approx year? Anything about the trip or the man/woman?

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly, the man was dressed in a cowboy suit, can't remember the woman well but I think she was blonde or redhead, the trip was a space colony that landed on the planet and started hearing this "noise" that drove them insane and made them suicide or something similar. Approx year is 2012-13, it's a long webcomic, just one image, nothing else that I know of, except he escaped the planet when his captain made a sacrifice, that's as far as I can remember.

Comment: That makes me think of Michael Flynn's *January Dancer* etc. series, don't know that it became a comic strip though.

Comment: I updated my comment to give a bit more detail behind this webcomic strip, not sure if it was based on that novel, yet it might be.

Comment: You might want to check out Boulet's work - http://english.bouletcorp.com/#archives - he's been posting strips for several years now, and his strips are generally one long self-contained vertical piece, often with sci-fi and fantasy themes. I'm not sure if this is one of his but it sounds like it could be.

Comment: Looked at his archives, might be, thanks for leading me there, found some neat stuff, but still nowhere to be found although some of his comics have a similar style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Subnormality* #138, "A Christmas Eve in the Future"](http://www.viruscomix.com/page505.html).

> a man, dressed in a cowboy suit who goes into a brothel, a woman who offers her services,

The woman is actually the one in the cowboy suit.

> he starts telling her a story about his unforgettable and terrifying trip to a planet

Yes.  Yes, he does.

> a space colony that landed on said planet and started hearing this "noise" that drove them insane and made them suicide or something similar

I don't see any mentions of "noise" in the text, and the inhabitants of the planet are actually soldiers sent to guard a drill site, not colonists.  However, everything breaks down, and they all start experiencing nightmares that result in them trying to avoid sleep.  The commander commits suicide and most of the others die soon after.  Then things get worse.

Comment: Thank you! It's this exact one, finally, I can read it once more, yes, I had the details a bit backwards, I read it a long time ago.